# AWS SimpleDB - less dense drives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

In the [FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/faqs/) of AWS SimpleDb service I have noticed paragraph

> Q: When should I use Amazon S3 vs. Amazon SimpleDB?
>
> Amazon S3 stores raw data. Amazon SimpleDB takes your data as input
>   and indexes all the attributes, enabling you to quickly query that
>   data. Additionally, Amazon S3 and Amazon SimpleDB use different types
>   of physical storage. Amazon S3 uses dense storage drives that are
>   optimized for storing larger objects inexpensively. Amazon SimpleDB
>   stores smaller bits of data and uses less dense drives that are
>   optimized for data access speed.

Can somebody explain how **AWS SimpleDB** reach high data access speed with using of **less dense drives**?

As I know: more density -> more speed.

Comment: Can you provide more details of what information you are seeking? Do you have a reference to it having "less dense drives" (less than what)?

Comment: @JohnR , thanks for advice. I've added link to quote, which led me to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SimpleDB is a non-relational (NoSQL) data store. These days, if you're looking to use NoSQL on AWS, DynamoDB is recommended. SimpleDB is not even listed on the service menu.

It can reach high speeds because it is a database (with item-level data pre-loaded and indexed), while Amazon S3 is an object store (that only works at the object level).

Comment: Thus there are no info about density of storage drivers. It's interesting more about disk storage than data format and database algorithms. How can **less dense** drivers be faster than **dense** drivers?
But probably it is a quite abstract question to get a detailed answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You can read these posts that may help you.

Check out:

1. [SimpleDB Essentials for High Performance Users: Part 1](http://practicalcloudcomputing.com/post/712653349/simpledb-essentials-for-high-performance-users)
2. [SimpleDB Essentials for High Performance Users: Part 2](http://practicalcloudcomputing.com/post/722621724/simpledb-essentials-for-high-performance-users)
3. [SimpleDB Essentials for High Performance Users: Part 3](http://practicalcloudcomputing.com/post/722637844/simpledb-essentials-for-high-performance-users)
4. [SimpleDB Performance : 5 Steps to Achieving High Write Throughput](http://practicalcloudcomputing.com/post/313922691/5-steps-simpledb-performance)